# In rails_admin, how can I filter on an association count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

Using rails_admin 0.6.2, I've added a custom field for a count of associated objects. For example, in a list of blog posts, show how many comments each has.

```
config.model Post do
  list do
    field :id
    field :comment_count, :integer do
      def value
        bindings[:object].comment.count
      end
      filterable true
    end
```

I want to be able to filter based on this number - show me posts with 0 comments, between 1 and 10, etc.

Right now there's no way it could do that, as this count is just created with an N+1 query; every time it lists a post, it queries for the comment count. I would need it to add a `WHERE` condition to its earlier query for the posts.

Answer (score 7):

### Use a scope

You can specify scopes that the list view can use and it will create a tab for each scope. Eg:

```
list do
  scopes [:with_comments, :with_no_comments]
 ...
```

Then you just need model scopes that check for those. Eg:

```
# app/models/post.rb
scope :with_comments, -> {
  where("id IN (#{Comment.select("DISTINCT post_id").to_sql})")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on Post model `has_many :comments, counter_cache: true`.  Then just add scope of filter.  It will be faster.  Checkout counter_cache docs for ActiveRecord.